# What next() means in TinkerPop

Tags: titan, tinkerpop3

I'm currently reading the TinkerPop3 [Documentation](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/)

What I'm confused is that I can't find any explanation about `next()`.

For example, w/ next() or w/o next() returns same vertext

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'marko').next()
==>v[1]
```

but, the class names are different from each other.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'marko').getClass()
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'marko').next().getClass()
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerVertex
```

Without 'next()' an assigned variable has no value.

```
gremlin> marko = g.V().has('name', 'marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> marko
```

Even, with `clockWithResult()` the outputs are completely different.

```
gremlin> clockWithResult(1){g.V().both().barrier().both().barrier().both().barrier().count().next()}
==>1.079524
==>72
gremlin> clockWithResult(1){g.V().both().barrier().both().barrier().both().barrier().count()}
==>0.11863599999999999
==>[GraphStep([],vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2147483647), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2147483647), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2147483647), CountGlobalStep]
```

or this example:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).out('knows').values('name').fold()
==>[vadas, josh]
gremlin> g.V(1).out('knows').values('name').fold().next()
==>vadas
==>josh
```

In the manual, there are many other examples which make me confusing.

I hope marko and his friends would help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The short answer is that the Gremlin Console iterates results for you automatically.

```
x = g.V().has('name', 'marko')
```

In the above example, `x` will be a `Traversal` instance, which is a type of `Iterator`.  When the console encounters an `Iterator` it automatically unrolls it so that you can see the results.  In this case:

```
x = g.V().has('name', 'marko').next()
```

the addition of `next()` just says that you want to call `Iterator.next()` - in other words you want to get the first item out of the `Iterator`.  So, in the above case, `x` will be a `Vertex`.

For this case:

```
gremlin> marko = g.V().has('name', 'marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> marko
```

you now know that `marko` is an `Iterator`, so when you evaluate it on again, the console tries to iterate it.  Of course, the console already iterated it on the previous line, so when it attempts to do so again, there is nothing additional to iterate.  Here's an example that makes it more apparent as to what is going on:

```
gremlin> x = g.V();null
==>null
gremlin> x.next()
==>v[1]
gremlin> x.next()
==>v[2]
gremlin> x
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

Note the use of `;null` on the first line which prevents the console from iterating `x`. Why? because my script returns `null` not the `x`.

It should now be clear as to what your example with `clock` is doing...the first  line which calls `next()` is measuring the execution of the traversal and the second is measuring the execution of the `Traversal` construction.  Why do you need to call `next()` in this case? Because the `Traversal` is inside of a closure - remember, the Console only iterates the return value of the function not every `Iterator` in your scripts.

Finally:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).out('knows').values('name').fold()
==>[vadas, josh]
gremlin> g.V(1).out('knows').values('name').fold().next()
==>vadas
==>josh
```

hopefully everything else I've discussed above allows you to see why the `next()` produces this behavior, but just in case, here's what the console is doing essentially:

```
gremlin> x = g.V(1).out('knows').values('name').fold();null
==>null
gremlin> y = x.next();null
==>null
gremlin> y
==>vadas
==>josh
```

Comment: Every gremlin snippets is excerpted from [TinkerPop3 Documentation](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#barrier-step)

So, "Why do you need to call next() in this case?" => the manual called `next()` ;)

Comment: Would you please answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285006/index-does-not-work-when-using-order-by-in-titan)? I really appreciate it if you can.